# A program worked fine on my computer but when I sent it on another one with a Dutch Windows it has problems with the DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, sql-server

The program is with C# WinForms and SQL Server 2008. When I want to enter data that includes the value from a DateTimePicker I can see that the wording is in Dutch and then I get an error about converting of the value. Is there any way to pre-program it to get around this? I've caught the error and here it is.

[image: error]

```
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Localhost\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            /******************** Inserting ********************/
            string query = "INSERT INTO spending VALUES (";
            query += "'" + date_dateTimePicker.Value + "', "; // Date
            query += "'" + Convert.ToDecimal(amount_spent_textBox.Text) + "', "; // Amount spent
            query += "'" + spent_on_textBox.Text + "')"; // Spent on
            connect.Open();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connect);
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connect.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
```

Things are getting thick.. I got this error while trying to insert a dateTimePicker value into the database the same way I did with the code above. It worked perfectly fine on my computer but it won't work here. Can someone explain? Here is the error:

[image: error]

Code used:

```
string update = "UPDATE table SET the_date = '" + the_date_dateTimePicker.Value + "' WHERE instance_ID = 1";
        connect.Open();
        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(update, connect);
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connect.Close();
```

Ok here is the full code for the form I am working on now, the one that shows [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWfSV.jpg). Most of the forms are structured like this so if I get this one right, there shouldn't be any problems with the rest of them. I'm testing this on my computer so if it works here it should work there also.

Take a look, I don't know what to do anymore.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TheNamespace
{
public partial class submit_spending : Form
{
    public submit_spending()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void submit_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Localhost\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=TheDataBase;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            /******************** Inserting ********************/
            string query = "INSERT INTO spending VALUES (@date, @amount_spent, @spent_on)";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date_dateTimePicker.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("amount_spent", Convert.ToDecimal(amount_spent_textBox.Text));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("spent_on", spent_on_textBox.Text);

            connect.Open();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connect);
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();

            if (MessageBox.Show("Submitted.", "Spending submitted", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void cancel_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Need the code where you are getting the date from the picker. Shouldn't be any string to date conversion involved in this.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson

There's the code for the inserting of the values, which it can't do on that computer so I have the catch and that's where I got the error image from.

Comment: @Tony actually, given that he seems to be concatenating a string here to build the query, looks like that could be it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber. Definitely, Another reason to use parameterised queries

Comment: @TonyHopkinson

Is there a simple parameterised query solution that would work with my code here or am I going to have to learn and rework a lot more?

Comment: @Minustar has does done one of them just now. It's not a lot to learn, but never build an sql string from anything that could be user input, is a must and a good habit. Savea lot of time to just pick up the habit and make concatenating sql from strings an execption. The advantage in your case, is you'll be using DateTime types for datetimes, not some locale based string conversion of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use an explicit ToString with a culture-invariant format to make sure that this works in any locale. This is a bit of a hack, but replacing this line:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date_dateTimePicker.Value);
```

with this should work:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date_dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("s"));
```

This will give you an ISO 8601 formatted date-time string, which is an international standard with an unambiguous specification. Also, this format is not affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE setting on your SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 8):

You should use the `Parameters.AddWithValue()` method. I would expect it to format the `DateTime` correctly.

```
string cmdText = "UPDATE table SET colX = @value WHERE id = @currId";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value", dateTimePicker1.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("currId", id);
```

Comment: When I try

`string query = "INSERT INTO spending VALUES (@date, @amount_spent, @spent_on)";

                connect.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date_dateTimePicker.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("amount_spent", Convert.ToDecimal(amount_spent_textBox.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("spent_on", spent_on_textBox.Text);`

It says [this](http://i.imgur.com/6n7Xu.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure that `date` isn't null? You could also connect after creating the command. I haven't a computer with C# near me to test this.

Comment: I tried opening the connection after the code but the same error appears. The date can't be null because it comes from a dateTimePicker which has its default value always set to Now/Today.

Comment: I created a small program; and it seems to work. The source is available on http://pastebin.com/aPUEG5dW; note that it is compiled on a Win7 64bit machine with a en-DA (English/British in Denmark) locale. Replace the `******` in the `SqlConnection` construction with whichever connection string you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have problem with date time formating, It can be solved by changing the systems datetime format into the same one as in the computer it was working, or you can do some additional work in your code. For custom datetime formats Have a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Or you could simply output the date in a format the server can understand via `ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should write your application using `datetime` parameters in the T-SQL statements so that conversions never come into picture.

The other avenue at your disposal is to add a [`SET DATEFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) on the connection(s) used by your app. You can thus change the format to the one your application expects/uses.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need specify the SqlDBType when assigning the values to date in command.Parameters .and please cross check the parameter names which you have specified in insert statement with the parameters specified in parameters.Add

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO spending VALUES (@date, @amount_spent, @spent_on)";
 using (var cn = new SqlConnection("..connection string.."))
 using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
   {
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date_dateTimePicker.Value;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount_spent",Convert.ToDecimal(amount_spent_textBox.Text));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spent_on", spent_on_textBox.Text);

        connect.Open();
```

Some time its better to use invariant culture to store things like date/time in database .You can try that CultureInfo.Invariantculture

```
DateTime date = date_dateTimePicker.Value.Date;
string sDate = date.ToString("dd-MM-yy",    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dateInsert = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"UPDATE table SET the_date = '" + the_date_dateTimePicker.Value + "' WHERE instance_ID = 1";
```

A conversion to String using default CultureInfo happens here. DateTime can be converted to both "29/05/2012" and "05/29/2012" depending on the regional settings selected on your workstation. However Sql Server might be configured for another regional settings and thus you have a problem(sql server cannot parse passed string representation of DateTime)

You have to use parametrized query if you don't want to face another CultureInfo-related issue later.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `dateTime.ToString("s")`, it will give your date time in universal format regardless of cultural settings of the computer.